# jquery ui bounce effect causing elements to fall out of place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to create a bounce effect but when I hover the mouse over the area the elements fall out of place. How do I ensure they stay in a line?

I have three icons in a row like this

```
  %span
    =link_to image_tag("icons/github_alt.svg", class: '')
  %span
    =link_to image_tag("icons/last.fm.svg", class: '')
  %span  
    =link_to image_tag("icons/soundcloud.svg", class: '')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tkn02tut/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with

```
span.social_icon {display:block; float:left; margin: 5px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alemarch/tkn02tut/1/

is this?